# Equal Row Height in Sibling Flexbox Items/Columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have multiple products with a heading, a description and a call-to-action. The word count of each is not regulated. I am using flexbox to display these products so that the containers of each item will be of equal height and can clear to the next row easily without having to mess with nth-child.

My question is this. Is there a flex property (or other CSS property) that can allow me to match the height of rows in separate columns?

**Codepen**
http://codepen.io/fedaykin00/pen/yexOLV

**[Desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4E9V.jpg)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-row item-heading">
      <h1>Item 1: Far far away</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item-row item-body">
      <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows
        by their place and supplies it with the necessary</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item-row item-cta">
      <a href="#" class="cta">Far far away</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-row item-heading">
      <h1>Item 2: A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item-row item-body">
      <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item-row item-cta">
      <a href="#" class="cta">A wonderful serenity</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-row item-heading">
      <h1>Item 3: One morning, when Gregor Samsa</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item-row item-body">
      <p>One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections. The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment. His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item-row item-cta">
      <a href="#" class="cta">One morning</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-row item-heading">
      <h1>Item 4: The quick, brown fox</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item-row item-body">
      <p>The quick, brown fox jumps over a lazy dog. DJs flock by when MTV ax quiz prog. Junk MTV quiz graced by fox whelps. Bawds</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item-row item-cta">
      <a href="#" class="cta">The quick</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-row item-heading">
      <h1>Item 5: Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item-row item-body">
      <p>Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules. Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca: On refusa</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item-row item-cta">
      <a href="#" class="cta">Li Europan</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background-color: darkred;
  padding: 0.5em;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  width: calc((100% - 3em) / 3);
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 1em 1em 0 1em;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.item-row {
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: white;
}
.item-row.item-cta {
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.item-row.item-cta a {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

h1,
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

**As Outline**

- **.container** (flex-direction: row)

  - **.item** (flex-direction: column)

    - **.item-row.item-heading**

      - **h2**
    - **.item-row.item-body**

      - **p**
    - **.item-row.item-cta**

      - **a[href]**
  - **.item** (flex-direction: column)

    - **.item-row.item-heading**

      - **h2**
    - **.item-row.item-body**

      - **p**
    - **.item-row.item-cta**

      - **a[href]**

If and when the content of one item's h2 fills two lines, but another only fills one line, I would like to be able to match the height of both of their parent elements (.item-row.item-heading). The same goes for the other instances of .item-row, when they/their children have disparate heights. I want to avoid having to manually set heights based on current content, as I'll have to change it when that content changes.

I'm new to flexbox, so I'm not sure I know all of the properties and how they work. There may be no built-in way to do this. I'm sure there's a way to throw some scripts in the mix to make it do what I want, but I'm trying to avoid that if possible.

Comment: yeah this is possible. Check this: http://clearleft.com/thinks/270 and codepen example: http://codepen.io/lottejackson/pen/PwvjPj

Comment: @pivemi Thanks for the response. Yeah, I came across that article when I was trying to find a solution. Unfortunately, the 'equal height' aspect there is only referring to the main items (.list-item in her example, .item in my example), whereas I'm wanting the rows _inside_ .list-item/.item to be of equal height.

Comment: I understand. Didn't have much time hence the quick copy and paste. I saw <p> tags are stretched in the example though (which is why the <a> is pushed down). Not possible to apply to the row inside the element?

Comment: @pivemi I see what you're saying. That seems to be from 'flex-grow:1;' on the <p>, telling it to expand to fill the space available, though it seems to only act within its parent element, unaware of the height of its ... cousin (?) elements.

Even though this doesn't make it do precisely what I wanted, this is not useless information, so thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `matchHeight`:

Your code:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/debraj/38jtno6a/10/
```

Full documentation here:

```
http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/
```

Comment: I'm trying to see if there's a CSS-only method to solve the problem, but this is very useful in case there is no way to do it without JS.

**Updated pen with your JS and flex-grow from @pivemi:**
http://codepen.io/fedaykin00/pen/KVxzgN. 

If I ever reach 15 rep, you'll have an upvote.

Comment: You hardy do this dynamic stuffs with CSS, as with jQuery or JavaScript they are more robust.

Answer (score 0):

A minimal way to achieve this with Javascript is [here](http://codepen.io/hartliddell/pen/LZEbKw?editors=1111).

```js
function setAllToMaxHeight($el) {
  
    var maxHeight = 0;

    $el.each(function() {
        var height = parseInt($(this).css('height').replace('px',''), 10);
        maxHeight = height > maxHeight ? height : maxHeight;
    });

    $el.css({ 'height' : maxHeight });  
}

setAllToMaxHeight($('.item-heading'));
```